# Literature on credit risk premia

Tags: fixed-income, quant-trading-strategies, credit, algorithm, strategy

I am looking for a comprehensive ressource describing known strategies of credit risk premia. Is there such kind of articles/books/websites?

Answer (score 3):

Two papers by AQR might be of use:

[Asvanunt, A. and S. Richardson (2016), “The Credit Risk Premium”](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2563482):

> Despite theoretical and intuitive reasons for a credit risk premium,
>   past research has found little supporting empirical evidence. This is
>   primarily due to biases in computing credit excess returns which
>   improperly account for term risk. Using data spanning 80 years in the
>   U.S., and nearly 20 years in Europe, we find strong evidence of credit
>   risk premium after correctly adjusting for term risk. The credit risk
>   premium is not spanned by other known risk premia and exhibits time
>   variation related to economic growth and aggregate default rates.
>   These results have important implications for asset pricing and
>   investment decisions.

[Asvanunt, A., Frieda, A., and S. Richardson, “Systematic Credit Investing”](https://www.aqrcapital.com/-/media/files/perspectives/systematic-credit-investing.pdf):

> This paper aims to increase familiarity of the credit asset class and
>   provide an overview of our approach to systematic credit investing. We
>   introduce credit instruments and outline a simple framework for
>   understanding sources of credit excess returns. We summarize two
>   avenues for approaching systematic credit investing (and provide many
>   references for readers interested in greater depth): (i) strategic and
>   tactical exposure to the overall credit risk premium and (ii) relative
>   value opportunities across credit instruments. We find that both kinds
>   of systematic credit exposure have the potential to provide meaningful
>   performance and diversification benefits to traditional and
>   alternative portfolios.

Also take a look at [Van Luu, B. and P. Yu (2011). The credit risk premium: should investors overweight credit, when, and by how much?](https://papers.ssrn.com/sol3/papers.cfm?abstract_id=2138885):

> The authors revisit the case for maintaining a strategic overweight to
>   corporate bonds in fixed income portfolios based on the notion of the
>   credit risk premium. Using a series of excess returns to
>   investment-grade corporate bonds going back to 1926, the authors find
>   evidence of a positive risk premium of corporate bonds over
>   Treasuries. However, investors who rely on a passive structural
>   overweight should be aware of the substantial additional tracking
>   error and the long payoff periods required. Second, they examine the
>   behavior of credit excess returns through many cycles, using the OECD
>   Composite Leading Index to divide economic activity into four
>   re-occurring phases. At the margin, the results are useful in guiding
>   portfolio managers and asset owners in their tactical decisions with
>   regard to the magnitude of the credit tilt.